# Find the context of a div within HTML

Tags: jquery, html

[image]

So I have created a table of contents that updates dynamically based on two tags placed on headings within the html. The two headings are toc-item (this is the displayed items name) and toc-level (this is the items level) with level 1 being the main headings and then as the levels go down, these items are indented and their numbering is changed based on this.

The jquery code for this is:

```
function drawOlForItems(itemsToDraw, parentIndex) {
    var $ol = $("<ol>");

    itemsToDraw.foreach(function (item, index) {
        var entryIndex = index + 1;
        var $li = $("<li class='toc-level-{0}'>".format(item.level));
        var itemIndex = parentIndex != null ? "{0}.{1}".format(parentIndex, entryIndex) : entryIndex;
        $li.append("<span class='entry-text'>{0}) {1}</span>".format(itemIndex, item.heading));
        //$li.append("{0}".format(item.heading));

        if (item.subItems.length) {
            var subItems = drawOlForItems(item.subItems, itemIndex);
            $li.append(subItems);
        }
        $ol.append($li);
    });

    return $ol;
}
```

and the HTML where it is injected into is here:

```
<div id="inject-toc-here" style="font-family:'Century Gothic'" data-show-
numbers="" data-cssNumbering=""></div>
```

As seen in the picture it seems to work just fine. However in the html the headings "4th level V3" and "3rd Level Test2" are actually placed underneath "1.2) Banking Details" header. So is there anyway I can make my code aware of where it is in the HTML and based on that place the sub-levels accordingly.

Thanks in advance.(And yes my HTML is all correct, I have tried multiple things but nothing seems to work)

EDIT:
After using the dev tools I now see that my list creator is selecting the wrong parent to attach to. This is the code creating the list.

```
 function getNestedItems() {
    var entries = [];
    var nested = [];

    $("[toc-item]").each(function (index, element) {
        var toc = new TocEntry();

        var $tocEntry = $(element);
        var level = parseInt($tocEntry.attr("toc-level"));
        var heading = $tocEntry.attr("toc-item");
        //var prevEntry = previous;

        var parent = nested.first(x => x.level == level - 1);

        toc.heading = heading;
        toc.level = level;
        toc.level = level;

        if (parent) {
            parent.subItems.push(toc);
        } else {
            nested = [];
            entries.push(toc);
        }

        nested.push(toc);

        //privates
        function TocEntry() {
            return {
                heading: heading,
                level: null,
                subItems: []
            };
        }
    });
```

As you can maybe see what happens is that the first() selector is selecting home email as the parent but not banking details. Any ideas how to use banking details as the parent rather?

Comment: Can you post the HTML that is rendered? Where exactly are the Elements rendered in the wrong order? From what you've posted, I can't quite tell what you're asking.

Comment: @KWeiss the html that is rendered is the picture that is linked. The elements that are rendered wrong are 4th level V3 and 3rd level Test2 in the picture.

Comment: In the picture, both headings appear to be in the correct place. What do you mean by "However in the html the headings [...] are actually placed underneath "1.2) Banking Details" header." ?

Comment: @KWeiss so in the HTML the div containing those two headings are placed vertically under banking details. However I now see what the problem is. Will edit my post with new info